# Where can I get outage updates/alerts for transoceanic cables (and other tier-1 fiber backbones)?

Tags: internet, fiber, packetloss, outage

Is there some site that aggregates status updates from the companies that manage the transoceanic fiber cables so that I can get a world view of global internet outages that break connectivity between continents for millions of users in semi-real-time?

Several times per year, I end up on a network that's insufferably unusable due to packet loss, and `traceroute` shows that the issue isn't:

1. between my laptop and my WAN modem nor
2. between my WAN modem and the next few hops through my ISP's network

But the issue appears to be on some other pipe downstream from my ISP whoose DNS suggests it's operated by a tier 1 provider, such as Level3.net (Lumen Technologies).

Moreover, the packet loss is only detectable when using 10%-30%-ish of the internet, and it roughly appears to be regional--perhaps a transatlantic route.

That's about as much debugging as I can do with `traceroute`. The next thing I usually do is try to find a "status" page for the company whoose line is flapping, but all I can usually find on their website is content marketing trash.

How do I know if the transoceanic pipes are clogged or running smooth? Where is that magical dashboard that shows the world's Internet backbone status, per provider--or as close as we can hope for?

More generally, where can I go to find out if the [largest operators of the world's fiber networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tier_1_network#List_of_Tier_1_networks) (Lumen, Verizon, Liberty Global, Tata, AT&T, etc) are experiencing issues that may be causing issues that affect millions or billions of people using the Internet right *now*?

Comment: Many communications companies and ISP’s offer a “looking glass” site/page that shows the informed reader an insight into their network routing health and status

Comment: @HermanB hey, thanks, found this from Level 3 = CenturyLink. But I'd also like a log of outage alerts (compiled by a human, with an RCA) for previous network issues over time (ideally the past years, but at least the past days) https://lookingglass.centurylink.com/

Comment: Sadly, the CenturyLink looking glass (see link in above comment) explicitly says it's "not to be used with any automated scripts/applications" -- that doesn't help achieve my imaginary "magical dashboard of the world's Internet backbone status"